# Where are the light settings in Blender 2.8?

Tags: light

I'm trying to follow a tutorial but got stuck when I tried to setup the lights. Here's a screenshot from the tutorial:

[image]

Where are these settings in 2.8?

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.80 the Light settings have been moved into the Object Data Panel.

Select your light source in the Outliner, then select the Object Data tab.

Light settings EEVEE:

[image: Blender 2.8 Light Settings EEVEE]

Light settings Cycles:

[image: Blender 2.8 Light Settings Cycles]